# Regex select several lines until two consecutive new lines is not working on Mac

Tags: regex, macos, grep, text-extraction

I need to extract several lines of text (which vary in length along the 500 MB document) between a line that starts with *"Query #"* and two consecutive carriage returns. This is being done on a Mac. For example, the document format is:

```
Query #1: 020.1-Bni_its1_2019_envio1set1

lines I need to extract


Alignments (the following lines I don't need)

xyz
xyx

Query #2: This and the following lines I need. And so on.
```

There are always exactly two carriage returns before the word "Alignments". So basically I need all the lines from Query #.: until Alignments.

I tried the following regex, but I only recover the first line.

```
ggrep -P 'Query #.*?(?:[\r\n]{2}|\Z)'
```

I have tested the regex with multiple iterations [at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TWxecV/1), but I have not yet found the answer.

The expected output is:

```
Query #1.   Text.

Lines I need to extract

Query #2: This and following lines I need.

Lines I need.

Query #....
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do add samples of expected output also in your question, thank you.

Comment: What version of mac are you using? Mine doesn't have a `P` flag.

Comment: Try `ggrep -oPz 'Query #.*(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*'` or if `ggrep` is pcregrep, `ggrep -oM 'Query #.*(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*'`

Comment: The first three lines are `"Query #1: 020.1-Bni_its1_2019_envio1set1\n\nlines I need to extract\n"`, so "lines" is preceded by two line terminators, which on a Mac are two line feed characters, (not carriage returns). Perhaps you mean three consecutive newlines.

Comment: Thanks. @wiktor.stribizew for the code. It worked, but the text "Query #." was omitted from the extracted text and it is needed.  And yes, I ended up using `pcregrep` command on Mac High Sierra. Not sure what `(?!\R{2}) does.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you are right, I miss counted the line feeds.  The code that ended up working was:  `pcregrep -oM '(?s)Query #.*?(?:[\r\n]{3}|\Z)'` which extracted the desired text. Thanks!

Comment: Efuchs, `\R` matches any Unicode newline character sequence, the main ones being `'\r\n'` for Windows and `\n` for Linux and Mac. `\R` is It is supported by the PCRE regex engine, the engine used by `Java`, and possibly others. It is not supported by Ruby, Python, Javascript and others. `\r?\n` is commonly seen as it works with all engines. `(?:\R.*)*` matches zero or more lines beginning with a line terminator and the next line up to its line terminator. However, you need to stop when there are three line terminators in a row, hence @Wiktor suggests matching `(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pcregrep`, you can use

```sh
pcregrep -oM 'Query #.*(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*' file.txt > results.txt
```

Here,

- `o` - outputs matched texts
- `M` - enables matching across lines (puts line endings into "pattern space")
- `Query #.*(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*` matches

  - `Query #` -  literal text
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\R(?!\R{2}).*)*` - zero or more sequences of a line break sequence (`\R`) not immediately followed with two line break sequences (`(?!\R{2})`) and then the rest of the line.

Test screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This answer still leaves the "Query #1..." text out, which is necessary to identify the Query.

Comment: @Efuchs The matches are all as expected, as you described in the question.

Comment: The text ought to be provided [as text, not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).

Answer (score -3):

From *[Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)*:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Using any [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) implementation in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '/^Query #/{f=1} /^Alignments/{f=0} f' file
```

Output:

```
Query #1: 020.1-Bni_its1_2019_envio1set1

lines I need to extract


Query #2: This and the following lines I need. And so on.
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include expected output as suggested by @EdMorton, for future references.  I love AWK, but for some reason I never think of it unless is tabular data. And to be honest it takes a lot more effort to remember than grep. But your solution also worked. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Awk takes more effort than grep for you to remember because you're used to using grep. If you used awk instead you'd find it easy to remember and easier to solve problems like your current one. The expected output you put in a question should be the output you expected from the input you provide so we can run a script against your input to see if it produces your output or not for an immediate pass/fail result. The expected output you added seems unrelated to the input you provided.